# Excel Formula Query on Summing Annual Leave Days and Half Days

Tags: excel, count, formula, countif, tracker

so challenge for this week. I am creating a leave tracker for a number of employees. This tracker tracks the annual leaves, parental leaves, half days, work from homes and sick leaves.

There are 12 tabs and each tab represents the calendar month highlighting the days and dates. Each tab also has a total column at the end calculating the number of annual leaves and half days **only** (as the others are not deducted from their annual allowance).

Annual Leaves = A

Half Days = HA

Is there a formula I can use to sum up the annual leaves **and** half days for each employee where **half days** is equal to **0.5 of a day** rather than a day? So if one has **2 days annual leave** in January and **3 half day leaves** in January; what formula can I use to show **3.5**?

**FYI -** I would like a single formula to calculate the above rather than 2 separate columns to calculate annual and half days leaves separately which then are summed together in a third tab.

Comment: Something like `=SUM(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,"A"),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8,"HA")/2)` - total count of `A`, and total count of `HA` divided by 2.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. But I understand your concept. Let me play around with the formula and see what works exactly. So the half days are being counted as 1 rather than 0.5.

Comment: @IzaBella divided by 2 means 1 is 0.5 ...

Comment: never mind, he conditional formatting was set to whole numbers

Comment: Is there a way to count all the sick leaves for every sheet for every employee?